# Reader/getResourceAsStream returns null

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read from a json file to a reader in order to parse it into a java object:`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        try(Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(main.class.getResourceAsStream(
               "/Users/edwardk/IdeaProjects/practice_json/small_incidents.json"),"UTF-8")){
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            Person p = gson.fromJson(reader, Person.class);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Im getting a NullPointerException on run.

Comment: getResourceAsStream() gets a resource, from the classpath. To read a file, from the file system, use a FileInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

[Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) are not [files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html), and that path `/Users/edwardk/...` looks like a file path.

You should use the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API to read from a file, and if you're on Windows your path will need to start with `C:/`, not `/`. If you intended to load the file as a reasource you should use a path to the file relative to your classpath. For example if the `practice_json` directory is on your classpath you may just need to use `"small_incidents.json"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good, but `NullPointerException` arises because

```
main.class.getResourceAsStream(
               "/Users/edwardk/IdeaProjects/practice_json/small_incidents.json"),"UTF-8")
```

returns null. Try to paste json file into same directory as main.java and change :

```
main.class.getResourceAsStream(
               "small_incidents.json"),"UTF-8")
```

Or specify correct relative path to `small_ingredients.json`

Comment: This was indeed the problem, I've resolved it by moving the json file to the Recourses directory.